# PHP file put content- Null printing when the connection is down

Tags: php, json

I send to the server some data and then get another array from db.
then I need to create a **JSON** file with all that data 
the problem is sometimes when the connection between client and server is broken , the logger print  null row in notepad++ (or empty row in mac).
My question is how can I prevent that and send error while the file put contents create a null file

Maybe the `file_put_contents()` is a problems with unicode or something ?
for exmaple in array the will print to the json I have :

```
/images/folder/x.jpg
```

code:

after I get the params from client (maybe they are null in this time)
How can I make sure the php will not create a damaged file

```
$file = $this->getPath();
    $jsonData = json_encode([
        'key'           => time(),
        'key1'           => $paramsFromClientProbablyNull,
        'key2'        =>"constant",
        'key2'   => "constant" ,
        'list'  => $listOfUrls
    ]);

    if ($jsonData === false)
        throw new Exception("Could not encode json");

    //write json 
    if(!file_put_contents($file, $jsonData))
        throw new Exception("Could not write");

    return true;
```

Comment: i am not understanding the question completely but i have a feeling you are looking for `try { //your code } catch(\Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php